# Ada compilation "does not contain expected unit"

Tags: ada

I have a program that is written in Ada, and I need to compile it. When I do so, I get a "does not contain expected unit" error, and it says it is expecting a spec but found a body. I need it compile it, and I don't know about Ada. I am using the gnat compiler. and i cant put any code up but i can say that it is a adb file with other ads files in the folder.

Comment: What compiler? What is the code? What is the file name? We need *something* to go on.

Comment: @Marc is right. Often the actual error messages output by the compiler will help us a lot (and as you get used to the compiler they will help you; not much consolation right now, I know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error :

```
"does not contain expected unit"
```

usually occurs when the name of the unit does not match the file name (`package body aaa.bbb` needs to be in file `aaa-bbb.adb` and `package aaa.bbb` needs to be in `aaa-bbb.ads`)

```
"expecting a spec but found a body"
```

probably means you have a mismatch between the contents of the file and the file extension (ads or adb)

Beyond this i can only upvote the comment by Marc C